# PHP Yml to Array

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

How do you propery parse a YML to array in PHP

I tried using the symfony yaml parse but somehow the php output is on a line by line basis and not group per underscore of data, is there a way we can group this per underscore?

```
---
-
    id: 53421926
    title: Dr.
    firstName: Donna
    lastName: Johnson
    company: Martin Ltd
    email: donna.johnson@robinson.org
    phoneNumber: (0043) 645 2768
    buildingNumber: 168
    streetName: Tom Locks
    city: Ellieburgh
    postcode: FK8 1LD
    county: West Yorkshire
    creditCardType: MasterCard
    creditCardExpirationDate: 10/20
-
    id: 11840806
    title: Dr.
    firstName: Ben
    lastName: Graham
    company: Reid Inc
    email: ben.graham@palmer.info
    phoneNumber: (08851) 360123
    buildingNumber: 98
    streetName: Patrick Branch
    city: Ianchester
    postcode: WA7 1EN
    county: North Yorkshire
    creditCardType: Visa
    creditCardExpirationDate: 10/18
-
```

Code

```
$output =  Yaml::parseFile($this->inputStoragePath.$filename);
```

Output is somewhat like this

```
 [1497] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     postcode: KA7 1TH
        )

    [1498] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     county: Suffolk
        )

    [1499] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     creditCardType: Visa
        )

    [1500] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     creditCardExpirationDate: 01/21
        )
```

Comment: What exactly were you expecting?  I parsed your file and got an array with two arrays as expected.  Was the --- at the beginning supposed to be significant?  And the very last -?

Comment: I was actually hoping to get 2 arrays as well. but it's not doing that. its putiing it on a new array everyline

Comment: The thing is, based on your output, your file is not even being parsed.  Just loaded with something that is reading the file and turning each line into an array.  I can't see how the yaml parser can possibly be doing that.  I copied/pasted your yaml file and then made a new project with just the yaml parser and it all worked as expected.  Might want to take a closer look at what your code is actually doing.  And maybe make a little test project yourself.

Comment: the file is being parsed the sample above is just the initial data on the file, that's my question actually I'm puzzled as well if I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

With symfony/yaml v5.1.5, using the exact Yaml file you posted, and the following code:

```
$output = Yaml::parseFile('/var/www/html/test.yaml');
dd($output);
```

I get this result:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:14 [▼
    "id" => 53421926
    "title" => "Dr."
    "firstName" => "Donna"
    "lastName" => "Johnson"
    "company" => "Martin Ltd"
    "email" => "donna.johnson@robinson.org"
    "phoneNumber" => "(0043) 645 2768"
    "buildingNumber" => 168
    "streetName" => "Tom Locks"
    "city" => "Ellieburgh"
    "postcode" => "FK8 1LD"
    "county" => "West Yorkshire"
    "creditCardType" => "MasterCard"
    "creditCardExpirationDate" => "10/20"
  ]
  1 => array:14 [▼
    "id" => 11840806
    "title" => "Dr."
    "firstName" => "Ben"
    "lastName" => "Graham"
    "company" => "Reid Inc"
    "email" => "ben.graham@palmer.info"
    "phoneNumber" => "(08851) 360123"
    "buildingNumber" => 98
    "streetName" => "Patrick Branch"
    "city" => "Ianchester"
    "postcode" => "WA7 1EN"
    "county" => "North Yorkshire"
    "creditCardType" => "Visa"
    "creditCardExpirationDate" => "10/18"
  ]
  2 => null
]
```

Could it be you didn't share the real yaml file content? By the way, an array is declared with a dash in yaml not with an underscore.